# What does “scarcely” imply when used with a quantity?

Tags: meaning

Does "scarcely" imply it is less than or more than when used with a quantity?

I have checked a few threads on the internet.

1)  He is **scarcely** four feet tall.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/barely-scarcely-hardly.800741/

2)  **Scarcely** twenty years passed before our imaginations were duly stretched.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/scarcely-twenty-years-passed.3225794/

3) " As the seventeenth century dawned, **scarcely** a hundred years after Columbus’s momentous landfall, the face of much of the New World had already been profoundly transformed. European crops and livestock had begun to alter the very landscape, touching off an ecological revolution that would reverberate for centuries to come."

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/scarcely-a-hundred-years-after.3570032/

In all of the above three examples, native speakers take "scarcely" to mean " a little more than".

This is confusing to me.

> Scarcely: only just; **almost not**  ( Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)

How would I understand the meaning of "scarcely" when used with a quantity?

Comment: You could replace **scarcely** in all your examples with the words **barely** or **hardly**.

Comment: Does it mean more than or less than or both depending on the context?

Comment: It means **only just** - **no more than**.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scarcely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster lists four different senses of [**scarcely**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scarcely):

> **1 a** : by a narrow margin : only just
>   // had *scarcely* rung the bell when the door flew open
>   — Agnes S. Turnbull
>   **1 b** : almost not
>   could *scarcely* see for the fog
>   **2 a** : certainly not
>   // could *scarcely* interfere
>   **2 b** : probably not
>   // there could *scarcely* have been found a leader better equipped
>   — V. L. Parrington

In each of your sentences, it's the first sense that the most applicable. Replace *scarcely* with *only just*.

---

Note that in the *almost not* sense that you mention (but which doesn't apply to your sentences), you can think of it as *just barely enough*. If I can *almost not* see, it means that I still *can* see—but if conditions change in any negative way, I won't be able to anymore. (It's the danger of not seeing that's being emphasized—while still expressing that it hasn't reached that point yet.)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification of "almost not".  This really helps.

Answer (score 2):

- **scarcely X** means in your examples **at least X, perhaps a tiny amount more**, but it also has the implication that X is to be considered small.
- He is **scarcely four feet tall** = no more than four feet tall
- **Scarcely twenty years** passed before = it only took twenty years ...
- **scarcely a hundred years after** = it only took 100 years for the effects to take place